# Super low duty cycle circuit

Tags: timer, 555, delay

I am looking for a way to recharge some glow in the dark paint in a way that isn't noticeable to others. My idea is to use a very fast pulse of light from a bunch of UV LEDs every few seconds, but where the pulse is below the human perceptibility range.

My first thought was a 555 timer, but that seems to struggle at less than 50% duty cycle as I look at all the online calculators. I dug up a digital PWM that I found in a drawer, but its lowest setting is 1% duty cycle and 1Hz.

I was thinking something more along the range of 0.01% duty cycle at 0.25Hz. What would be an appropriate way to solve this if not with a 555? Since I don't know exactly what the human perceptibility range is for a strobe of light, it would be nice to be adjustable so I can let it be on as long as possible as I test it.

Comment: If you need this to be charged in broad daylight, I don't understand the purpose of needing to do anything at all. If you need to charge it in the dark, it has to be charged faster than it discharges which means that short pulses would have to be proportionally brighter which would not be eye safe. What is the end goal here? Are you trying to charge something in daylight faster than it otherwise would? Are you trying to keep something glowing in the dark indefinitely?

Comment: Even if the pulse of UV isn't visible, won't the sudden increase in glow every 4 seconds be rather obvious?

Comment: I think the limit to "human perceptibility range" is the sensitivity limit of the eyeball observing and said spectra. There is such thing as [Persistence of Vision](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Persistence_of_vision) and more aptly [Flicker Fusion](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Flicker_fusion_threshold), which is to say we can't distinguish short pulses faster than some rate from a steady stream of light. But infrequent pulses, longer than the flicker fusion rate, could still be noticeable. A camera flash can be 1/1000 sec and that's easily noticeable.

Comment: My daughter painted my forklift with an image of Iron Man. We are using Strontium Aluminate glow in the dark which has a fast charge, slow discharge on his visor and the tank, which looks like the Arc Reactor. I don't have all the answers yet for the Hz, but was hoping to have the pulse be unnoticable. I just think it would be cool to have it glowing brightly at midnight rather than a dim glow and am looking for options.

Comment: And I assume due to the nature of the lines you can't stick actual lights in. Well, maybe the arc reactor but definitely not around the eyes anyways. I can't think of any good ways to go about this.

Comment: I have worked out the math with a TLC555 and you will need a dual TLC556 timer. One to create the long delay and the second to fire a very narrow pulse, so it is no longer a duty cycle conundrum for a single 555.

Comment: Maybe prototype with a function generator and a few transistors and de-risk the entire concept. If you get it working then you can easily design a circuit based on function generator settingsd that work.

Comment: I am thinking you can leave the UV lights on all the time. Just use UV lights that are not visible to the eye (or barely visible). Any visible pulse is going to be visually noticeable.

Comment: You could also use a simple microcontroller to approach this.

Comment: I found some Europium paint that is supposed to glow 30 hours and recharges fast. I will work with that to see what timers I need to keep it bright. Maybe it will be 30 seconds every 20 minutes. If I hide the LEDs behind a shroud, it should be good. http://unitednuclear.com/index.php?main_page=product_info&products_id=384

Comment: Please let me apprise you that generally all industrial LED Stroboscopes with 5500K Temp. work at 10 to 100 micro second light on time cycle at 5 to 200 Hz or more i.e. when a stroboscope is running at 50 Hz the pulse duration will be 1/50 sec = 0.02 sec and when fixed at 20 micro sec (0.00002 sec) light on time, then the duty cycle comes to 0.1 % (0.00002/0.02x100). Generally these stroboscopes run at 10 to 50 micro sec light on time i.e. from 0.075 to 0.25% duty cycle. So saying 0.01% duty cycle is possible with UV light only is not true. For more you may refer LED Stroboscopes....

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A flickering or flashing UV LED will be more noticeable than one that is continuously on at low power.

Just use a resistor from the forklift's 12V to power the LED

Answer (score 1):

If you really want to do low duty cycles always less than 50% with a 555, just invert the output, i.e. drive the LEDs on when the output is low.

Otherwise just use a MCU so you can get any kind of pattern to drive the LEDs.

Also running the LEDs constantly at low current would be just as same.